# Convert Month Name into Number C++

Tags: c++

I haven't touched C++ in a very long time and I'm sure this can be done in a one liner.

I have a string `day` that I want to convert into a value between 0-11.
I'd usually do something like this

```
months = array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr' ...);
print months[day];
```

But I have no idea how to do that in C++

Comment: I think single apices would be better around single chars.

Comment: You can use a std::map

Comment: What is the sense of month[day]. Do you mean month_name[month_number]? You write you have a string 'day'. What is the content of that string. Sorry, can't understand your question!

Answer (score 6):

A simple approach would be something like this:

```
vector<string> months = { "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", ... };
int month_number = 2;

cout << months[ month_number - 1 ] // it is month_number-1 because the array subscription is 0 based index.
```

A better, but more complex and advanced approach is to use `std::map` like below:

```
int get_month_index( string name )
{
    map<string, int> months
    {
        { "jan", 1 },
        { "feb", 2 },
        { "mar", 3 },
        { "apr", 4 },
        { "may", 5 },
        { "jun", 6 },
        { "jul", 7 },
        { "aug", 8 },
        { "sep", 9 },
        { "oct", 10 },
        { "nov", 11 },
        { "dec", 12 }
    };

    const auto iter = months.find( name );

    if( iter != months.cend() )
        return iter->second;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I have pressed the ctrl+enter by mistake and my edit was commited wrongly. See my current version for the answer

Comment: OK :-) But OP wants a index from 0..11 :-) And your solution crashes, if the month is not in the list, which is normally not acceptable.

Comment: how could the month not be in the list? i think I misunderstood the OP's question :-?

Comment: We don't know where the search string comes from. Maybe someone enters the string on the console or in an entry of a gui or read from a file?

Comment: just for not misinforming the OP, I have rewritten the same thing, but with iterators. so if the month name is wrong, then the iterator will go beyond the last valid one, so the function will return `-1`. I see now that somebody else wrote this here, so, it's your decision who's answer will be accepted!

Comment: "A better way"? It's doing the opposite of your first proposal.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `std::map` to write a function like this:

```
int GetMonthIndex(const std::string & monthName)
{
    static const std::map<std::string, int> months
    {
        { "Jan", 0 },
        { "Feb", 1 },
        { "Mar", 2 },
        { "Apr", 3 },
        { "May", 4 },
        { "Jun", 5 },
        { "Jul", 6 },
        { "Aug", 7 },
        { "Sep", 8 },
        { "Oct", 9 },
        { "Nov", 10 },
        { "Dec", 11 }
    };

    const auto iter(months.find(monthName));

    return (iter != std::cend(months)) ? iter->second : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I'd like to add:
You can put the string with the abbreviated month in a stringstream and use

```
int main() {
  std::string s = "Feb";
  std::stringstream ss(s);
  std::tm result;
  ss >> std::get_time(&result, "%b");
  std::cout << result.tm_mon << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

This takes the locale into account and can be adopted for different languages by imbueing the locale to the stringstream.

Answer (score -2):

you can use a simple switch, or a [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) , this is less verbose